# Is there any possibility of running the UI script in headless mode when we use the robot functions and * robot.click('google.png')

Tags: testing, karate

1. I am trying to run the script in headless mode(* **configure driver = { type: 'chrome', headless: true** } ) but it's failing due to usage of robot functions like

- robot.click('google.png')
- robot.input('oliver' + Key.ENTER) etc.
  Kindly suggest the solution to run in headless mode for this scenario.

2. If we combine API and UI in a single feature and running it in an headless mode the script fails. Because of API Scenario. Is there is a way to trigger in Headless mode for combining this two scenario. Because the response of API is passed in UI field. And the requirment is to keep it in a single feature file itself.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `robot` cannot be run in headless mode.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there any possibility to give an fix for this! - @peter

Comment: @oliver I think your best option is to contribute code or find someone who can do it for you. I can't think of any other options. robot is mostly used for desktop (windows) app automation